# Scala - Nested type keyword

Tags: scala, types, akka, akka-stream

I was going through Akka source code, and I came across the following

```
type Repr[+O] <: FlowOps[O, Mat] {
   type Repr[+OO] = FlowOps.this.Repr[OO]
   type Closed = FlowOps.this.Closed
}
type Closed
```

Can someone explain me what's going on here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FlowOps[O, Mat] {
   type Repr[+OO] = FlowOps.this.Repr[OO]
   type Closed = FlowOps.this.Closed
}
```

is a [compound type with a refinement](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#compound-types). Namely, `FlowOps[O, Mat]` by itself can have any `Repr` and `Closed` type members; here we require specific ones. This type is used as an upper bound for the type member `type Repr[+O]`.